# Uncaught Error: No model was found for 'model'

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm building an Ember-CLI app using the following:

```
DEBUG: Ember                          : 1.10.0
DEBUG: Ember Data                     : 1.0.0-beta.15
DEBUG: jQuery                         : 2.1.3
```

Using a form, I'm trying to save changes on 2 separate models.
One of the models (the user model) saves successfully, while the other (profile model) throws this error:

```
Uncaught Error: No model was found for 'userProfile'
```

**Models**

The two models in question are:

```
models/user.js
models/user/profile.js
```

user model:

```
import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.Model.extend({
    email: DS.attr('string'),
    username: DS.attr('string'),
    firstname: DS.attr('string'),
    lastname: DS.attr('string'),
    comments: DS.hasMany('comments'),
});
```

profile model:

```
import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.Model.extend({
  avatar: DS.attr('string'),
  educationDegree: DS.attr('string'),
  educationUniversity: DS.attr('string'),
  workRole: DS.attr('string'),
  workOrganisation: DS.attr('string'),
  interests: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

**Controller**

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  saved:false,
  actions: {
    save:function(){
      this.get('model.user').save();
      this.get('model.profile').save();
      this.set('saved',true);
    },
  },
});
```

**Route**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  model: function(){
    var _this = this;
    var currentUser = this.get('session.user');

    return new Ember.RSVP.all([
      _this.store.find('user', currentUser.id),
      _this.store.find('user.profile', {UserId: currentUser.id}),
    ]).then(function(values){
      return {
        user: values[0],
        profile: values[1].get('firstObject'),
      }
    });
  },
});
```

**Template**

```
<form {{action "save" on="submit"}}>
  {{input type="text" placeholder="First Name" value=model.user.firstname}}
  {{input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" value=model.user.lastname}}
  {{input type="email" placeholder="Email" value=model.user.email}}
  {{input type="text" placeholder="Affiliation" value=model.profile.workOrganisation}}
  <button type="submit" class="btn teal white-text">Save</button>
  {{#if saved}}
    <p class="text-valid">Save Successful.</p>
  {{/if}}
</form>
```

Comment: could you post the template and models?

Comment: Sure, I've added them now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs because Ember Data cannot find a model into which to insert the data coming back from the PUT ensuing from the save, which I assume looks like

```
{ userProfile: { ... } }
```

I don't know the exact rules by which Ember looks up models based on these "root keys" such as `userProfile`, but I doubt if it can find the `profile` model hiding down underneath `models/user/`.

In the past the following has worked for me, if you have control over the server:

```
{ "user/profile": { ... } }
```

If you can't change the server response, or this fails to work for some other reason, the simplest thing to do is to move the `profile` model up to the top level of the `models` directory and name it `user-profile.js`.

Another alternative is to play with `modelNameFromPayloadKey`:

```
// serializers/application.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    modelNameFromPayloadKey: function(payloadKey) {
        if (payloadKey === 'userProfile') payloadKey = 'user/profile';
        return this._super(payloadKey);
    }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Taking the profile model out of the user directory worked perfectly. Thank you for the choice of answers too :)